# Auto-update Windows on dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I am planning to set myself up a brand new dual boot Ubuntu/Windows machine in the next month or so. I use Ubuntu for 95% of everything but there are some games/software that I find too painful to emulate/do without, so I like to have Windows around as a fallback. Also, my wife uses Windows for some work things.

I had a dual boot machine before about a year ago, and the problem I ran into was that booting into Windows always took forever. Because I wasn't using Windows more than once or twice a month, it would always have a lot of updates and maintenance to perform before it was in a usable state. This made switching over to Windows more of a pain, which made me more reluctant to do it, which exacerbated the problem.

So, here is my idea, which I am hoping you can help with: If I leave Ubuntu running every evening, could I script it to reboot to Windows at 2am every night, wait a bit for Windows to apply it's updates, and then reboot back to Ubuntu? So every morning I'll be looking at the Ubuntu login, but if I need to switch over to Windows it should be pretty quick.

I realise this will involve both Ubuntu and Windows scripting, the latter of which is unlikely to be anyone's strong point here. Still, any help appreciated!

I'll probably be installing Ubuntu Desktop 19.10 and Windows 10.

Comment: Asking help with any Windows issue maybe off-topic here. But, I've read that many Windows 10 updates have been problematic and so auto-updating may not be the best way to go.

Comment: If Ubuntu is set at top of grub, computer should reboot back to it.  Used to do it with my windows updates.  Windows usually does not update more than once a month(used to anyway), but you still have to update manually your other programs.  Would just boot into windows once in a while at night and let it update.

Comment: @crip659: In my experience, Windows 10 has updates to apply about twice a week.

Comment: @DKBose There isn't really an option *not* to auto-update modern versions of Windows. Microsoft decided too many people were delaying security updates and they've curtailed freedom in that area a lot.

Answer (score 1):

An unattended reboot will choose the top item in the GRUB menu to boot from.

You would need to script in Ubuntu

1. a change of GRUB [to boot Windows, once](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html)
2. followed by a cron command to reboot at a time certain, then
3. when Windows boots, execute a script to run updates, and conditionally
   A.   either reboot again into Windows *if* more updates need to be performed,
   B.   or *if* no more need be done, change to GRUB to put Ubuntu back at the top, then
4. reboot into Ubuntu.

3A is especially tricky because Windows updates sometimes lead to more Windows Updates which cannot be performed until Windows reboots. You would need to find a way to conditionally execute one branch or the other of your Windows script depending on whether Windows needs you reboot and run more updates.

3B is even more risky, since writing to Linux filesystems from Windows is chronically troublesome and often results in filesystem corruption. I would recommend against it.

Comment: Is there a way of telling GRUB to reboot to Windows just next time, and then return to the default? Because then I wouldn't have to do 3B. 3A isn't too much of a problem, as Windows will get a chance to carry on with its updates the next night.

Comment: @Martin Eden See #1 above; found a way.